# Remove smallest p% numbers from multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

hope that everyone is doing 'fine' in these COVID-19 pandemic times! I have a problem which is as follows:

I have multiple numpy multidimensional arrays which have different random numbers in them. Now I need to remove the smallest magnitude numbers from all of the different numpy arrays. This is analogous to somehow storing all of the numbers from multiple arrays to a 1-D array and then removing the smallest magnitude numbers from them.

I know how to do this for individual numpy array. The code is as follows:

```
# Define 3 numpy arrays-
x = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 64))
y = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 128))
z = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 256))

x.shape, y.shape, z.shape
# ((3, 3, 64), (3, 3, 128), (3, 3, 256))

# Print a slice of 'x'-
# x[:,:, 0]


# Compute absolute values of 'x'-
x_mod = np.abs(x)

# Remove smallest (p = 10%) of absolute magnitude numbers to zero-
x_mod[x_mod < np.percentile(x_mod, 10)] = 0

# For removed numbers, have zero, otherwise the original values from 'x'-
x_fin = np.where(x_mod == 0, 0, x)
```

Is there a way to remove the smallest magnitude weights considering all of numpy arrays: x, y, and z (for this given example)?

I am using Python 3.8 along with numpy 1.18.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The current way I am achieving this problem is as follows:

```
# Create a numpy array concatenating all numpy arrays-
a = np.concatenate((x, y, z), axis = None)

a.shape
(4032,)

# Create absolute value for the numbers-
a_mod = np.abs(a)

# Remove the smallest 10% of magnitude based numbers-
a_mod[a_mod < np.percentile(a_mod, 10)] = 0

# Final array which has 0 for pruned numbers and the original number otherwise-
a_fin = np.where(a_mod == 0, 0, a)

# Take slices from 1-D numpy array and re-create different numpy arrays
# from above-
x_new = a_mod[:576].reshape(3, 3, 64)
y_new = a_mod[576:1728].reshape(3, 3, 128)
z_new = a_mod[1728:].reshape(3, 3, 256)

x_new.shape, y_new.shape, z_new.shape                                  
# ((3, 3, 64), (3, 3, 128), (3, 3, 256))
```

Is there a better way to achieve this because I have to handle about 20 or more numpy arrays and then creating absolute slices such as [576:1728] becomes error prone and does not scale up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten and concatenate all your numpy arrays, calculate the threshold with `np.percentile` and modify the original arrays based on this threshold.

```
import numpy as np

# Define 3 numpy arrays-
x = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 64))
y = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 128))
z = np.random.uniform(low = -1000, high = 1000, size = (3, 3, 256))

# your list of arrays
arrs = [x, y, z]

# flatten all arrays
flattened = [a.flatten() for a in arrs]
# calculate the thresshold
threshold = np.percentile(abs(np.concatenate(flattened)), 10)

# set values to 0 when smaller than thresshold
for arr in arrs:
    arr[abs(arr) < threshold] = 0
```